# Access URL of S3 files using Boto

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, boto, boto3

I have some images in my S3 bucket and I want to display them in my django application.

```
import boto3
s3=boto3.client('s3')
list=s3.list_objects(Bucket='my_bucket_name')['Contents']
for l in list:
    print(l[u'Key'])
```

Using this code I'm getting the names of those images. How do I get the URL of the images, so that I can pass it to HTML pages to display it, using this same approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

URLs to access files in S3 follow this format:

```
https://<region>.amazonaws.com/<bucket-name>/<key>
```

See here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAPI.html

And then utilize the django Template language (see here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/language/#) to inject what you need.

If your buckets were stored in a list, and keys for for each bucket were stored in a dictionary, you could do something like this:

```
{% for bucket in buckets %}
    {% for key in keys[bucket] %}
        <a href="https://<region>.amazonaws.com/{{ bucket }}/{{ key }}">S3 link here</a>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Yes. okay. I have to concatenate the URL starting part with the key for each image. How do I do that inside {{ }} in HTML?

Comment: I edited my answer to explain this. Django has a pretty powerful template library to inject HTML